# Get value from EditText into table in AWS DynamoDB

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-dynamodb

I want to put new items from textbox wrote by users into existing table in DynamoDB. However, I have encountered some errors that I dont really understand. Below are my codes:

Add method

```js
public class Add_Item
{
    private String title;
    private AmazonDynamoDBClient client;
    String tableName = "Tesis_FTSM";

    public void DynamoDBLoad() throws IOException
    {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new PropertiesCredentials(DynamoDBClient.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("AWSCredentials.properties"));
        client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
        client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
    }

    public void add()
        {
          
            final EditText title = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text1);
            String tajuk = title.getText().toString();
          
            Map<String, AttributeValue> item = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();

            try {
               item.put("Id", new AttributeValue().withS(tajuk));

                PutItemRequest itemRequest = new PutItemRequest().withTableName(
                        tableName).withItem(item);
                client.putItem(itemRequest);
                item.clear();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Create items failed.");
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

MainActivity

```js
public class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            Looper.prepare();

            try
            {
                Add_Item db = new Add_Item();

                db.DynamoDBLoad();
                db.add();
                  
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Looper.myLooper().quit();
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String page)
        {
            //onPostExecute
        }
    }
```

Logcat errors

```js
06-15 10:33:33.938  16885-17179/com.af.ftsm.testing W/System.err﹕java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 10:33:33.938  16885-17179/com.af.ftsm.testing W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1957)
06-15 10:33:33.938  16885-17179/com.af.ftsm.testing W/System.err﹕ at com.af.ftsm.testing.Add_Item.<init>(Add_Item.java:26)
06-15 10:33:33.938  16885-17179/com.af.ftsm.testing W/System.err﹕ at com.af.ftsm.testing.MainActivity$Task.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:50)
06-15 10:33:33.938  16885-17179/com.af.ftsm.testing W/System.err﹕ at com.af.ftsm.testing.MainActivity$Task.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:39)
06-15 10:33:33.938  16885-17179/com.af.ftsm.testing W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-15 10:33:33.938  16885-17179/com.af.ftsm.testing W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-15 10:33:33.938  16885-17179/com.af.ftsm.testing W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-15 10:33:33.938  16885-17179/com.af.ftsm.testing W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-15 10:33:33.938  16885-17179/com.af.ftsm.testing W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-15 10:33:33.938  16885-17179/com.af.ftsm.testing W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Is my method of adding items into table wrong or otherwise? Thank you.

Comment: what's Add_Item.java:26?

Comment: Hi. its Add_Item.java. It contains Add method.

Comment: Sorry, bad question. I meant what is at line 26? Based on the information, I believe the resource R.id.text1 doesn't exist, so findViewById returns null. Type cast on null will throw NPE.

Comment: ohh its ok now. I changed a bit of my codes!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information, I believe the resource R.id.text1 doesn't exist, so findViewById returns null. Type cast on null will throw NPE. If not, please tell us what is on line 26 of Add_Item.java.

PS: you'd better avoid PropertiesCredentials in a production level Android app. CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider is the recommended way of getting AWS credentials. See [Amazon Cognito Identity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/) for more details.